# Python: for each row, get next earlier date where value > 0

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to get current or past date where value was > 0. Will use this to calculate number of days since the value was > 0. In the case where date has value, then it will be 0 days.

Sample data and desired results shown below. Data is 'date' and 'value' column, and results are last two columns.

```
date        value   'date value > 0'    'days since value > 0'
2020-04-30  0       2020-04-28           2
2020-04-29  0       2020-04-28           1
2020-04-28  1       2020-04-28           0 
2020-03-31  6       2020-03-31           0
2020-03-30  1       2020-03-30           0
2020-03-29  3       2020-03-29           0
2020-02-29  0       2020-01-29           31
2020-01-31  0       2020-01-29           2
2020-01-30  0       2020-01-29           1
2020-01-29  1       2020-01-29           0
```

The data format could be either a dictionary or dataframe. I am importing from csv and will export back to csv.

Logic: for each row, filter to only records where date <= current row date, then get max date of filtered dataframe that have value > 0. Max date is the 'date value > 0'.

Edit: I have been trying iterating sequentially through dataframe records eg `pandas` `df.shift()`, `df.rolling()`, `df.iloc` but stuck on how to 'look back' to get date of previous record with value > 0.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Forgive me, I know this is poor format for SO. Normally I ask specific programming questions with code. Just needed to get past this block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a dataframe `data` with "date" column in `datetime64` type and "value" column in `int64` type:

```
>>> data
        date  value
0 2020-04-30      0
1 2020-04-29      0
2 2020-04-28      1
3 2020-03-31      6
4 2020-03-30      1
5 2020-03-29      3
6 2020-02-29      0
7 2020-01-31      0
8 2020-01-30      0
9 2020-01-29      1
>>> data.dtypes
date     datetime64[ns]
value             int64
dtype: object
```

Then you can sort the dataframe in ascending order of date, and then create a new column "prevdate" to copy the "date" column but set to `NaT` with the rows with value is 0, like this:

```
data['prevdate'] = data['date'].where(data['value'].ne(0))
```

and then forward fill the `NaT` values:

```
>>> data.sort_values('date', inplace=True)
>>> data['prevdate'] = data['date'].where(data['value'].ne(0)).fillna(method='ffill')
>>> data
        date  value   prevdate
9 2020-01-29      1 2020-01-29
8 2020-01-30      0 2020-01-29
7 2020-01-31      0 2020-01-29
6 2020-02-29      0 2020-01-29
5 2020-03-29      3 2020-03-29
4 2020-03-30      1 2020-03-30
3 2020-03-31      6 2020-03-31
2 2020-04-28      1 2020-04-28
1 2020-04-29      0 2020-04-28
0 2020-04-30      0 2020-04-28
```

Now you can simply take subtraction between the two date columns and convert the difference into integer:

```
>>> data['days'] = (data['date'] - data['prevdate']).apply(lambda x: x.days)
>>> data
        date  value   prevdate  days
9 2020-01-29      1 2020-01-29     0
8 2020-01-30      0 2020-01-29     1
7 2020-01-31      0 2020-01-29     2
6 2020-02-29      0 2020-01-29    31
5 2020-03-29      3 2020-03-29     0
4 2020-03-30      1 2020-03-30     0
3 2020-03-31      6 2020-03-31     0
2 2020-04-28      1 2020-04-28     0
1 2020-04-29      0 2020-04-28     1
0 2020-04-30      0 2020-04-28     2
```

Comment: Nice. I have been stuck on concept of iterating sequentially through column in some way eg `pandas` `df.shift()`, `df.rolling()`, `df.iloc`. I have used your fill forward technique in Excel before, but didn't even think of it for Python.